# Trouble adding SDK in IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm having trouble getting my SDK into my IntelliJ project.  I can't seem to get the path right or something.  This is the path that I'm using, which has all the packages in it.  I've tried adding numerous paths including the "sdk" folder and "sources" and it keeps not accepting the path, one message I'm getting is that it's "not a valid SDK path".

I can't seem to figure out what the correct path should be...

[image]

My SDK Manager:

[image]

Comment: You're talking about the android SDK. Might be worth tagging your question with android, don't you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need both Java SDK and Android SDK specified.

[Because of a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96256), you have to define JDK first (like `c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_37`).

Then define Android SDK by pointing to its root (in your case it would be `sdk` folder).

Comment: After adding the Java SDK `1.6.0_23` succesfully, it still says "The selected directory is not a valid home for Android SDK" when trying to add the SDK folder.  Do you know what specific file it's looking for in order to determine if it's a valid android SDK?

Comment: Android SDK directory should contain `platforms` directory with at least one **SDK Platform** downloaded there, [see the screenshot](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/2993/20121225210826.png).

Comment: I've added my SDK manager screenshot to the post.  It looks like I have all required components.

Comment: Yes, just purchased it during the "End of the World" sale

Comment: I retried everything after rebooting my PC and it worked.  Not sure why it didn't work before hand.  Thanks for the help!